# Why can't I add a type parameter to an overriding method?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I need to implement a method from a class `Foo`, in my subclass `Bar`:

```
class Foo {
    public abstract void foo();
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    
    private <T> Map<T, List<T>> getStuff() { ... }

    @Override
    public void foo() {
        Map<?, List<?>> stuff = getStuff();
        for (Entry<?, List<?>> e : stuff.entrySet()) {
            Object key = e.getKey();
            List<?> lst= e.getValue();
            lst.add(key);  // illegal: need ?, got Object
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, my method would benefit from a type parameter:

```
@Override
public <T> void foo() {
    Map<T, List<T>> stuff = getStuff();
    for (Entry<T, List<T>> e : stuff.entrySet()) {
        T key = e.getKey();
        List<T> lst= e.getValue();
        lst.add(key);  // legal!
    }
}
```

(I could also use raw types because I know it'll work, but everything I've read says you *really* shouldn't do that)

Unfortunately, this is illegal - my method `foo` in `Bar` "clashes with foo() in Foo; both methods have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other".

Which seems odd, given that my type parameter does not alter the parameters or return type of `foo` - any place it is okay to use `Foo.foo` in, it is also okay to use my (illegal) `Bar.foo` in.

My ugly hack of a workaround has, up until this point, been to just write a whole new (parameterized) method:

```
public void foo() {
    realFoo();
}

private <T> void realFoo() {
    // parameterized version of .foo() above
}
```

I have two questions:

1. Why does adding a type parameter to a method prevent it from overriding an unparameterized method in its superclass?
2. Is there a better way to get the behavior I want?

Comment: 1) after erasure, your methods are going to be the same. As such, you can't. 2) can't you make the `Foo::foo` parametrized?

Comment: The type of `getStuff()` is dangerous.  It can't _actually_ know the type of `T`, it has to use unsafe casts and have some other real type.

Comment: 1. You can't add type parameters to method overrides (or change the bounds of type parameters), because overrides have to have the same method signature, and type parameters are part of the signature. 2. "My ugly hack of a workaround" this is the right way to do it. Yes, it is ugly.

Comment: In this case `<T> void foo()` T is always going to be inferred to Object anyway. The compiler can't infer any more specifically, since there is no parameter or return type to narrow it down. So even if it were possible to do that, it would be completely useless. You could just as well replace every T in that method with Object. It's exactly the same.

Comment: @Eugene Unfortunately my subclass Bar is unusual in requiring a type parameter, and it doesn't really make sense to put one on Foo for logical/abstraction reasons (in my non-minimal use case).

Comment: @Michael Sure, but then I'd lose the benefit of parameterized typing - I could do lst.add("a string") and it would compile fine, even though the list is not guaranteed to allow strings.  But with T the compiler would tell me that a List<T> is not guaranteed to allow strings.

Comment: No, you're not losing anything. What I'm saying is that your specific usage of T (not all usages) is identical to using Object, just more confusing. You just think `T` is adding something when it's not. The compiler needs a way to be able to say "Oh, T is actually this more specific type". But in your case, you're not giving it anything to use when making that decision. Without any information, it's always Object. So just use Object.

Comment: @Michael It doesn't change the *behavior* of the method in my example, but it does change how the compiler interacts with it and how it is analyzed.  Suppose after `lst.add(key)` I added the line `lst.add("a string")`.  With Object, this would compile and then fail at runtime when the list is a ListThatOnlyAllowsIntegers.  With T, the compiler would fail and tell me that I can't add strings to lst because T is not bounded by String.  Thus, I prefer to have a type parameter here because it tells me when I've messed up my typing immediately, rather than at runtime.

Comment: I am reasonably surprised that `Map<?, List<?>> stuff = getStuff();` works: I would have thought you'd need it to be `Map<?, ? extends List<?>>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [JLS 8.4.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2):

> ## 8.4.2. Method Signature
>
> Two methods or constructors, M and N, have the same signature if they have the same name, the same type parameters (if any) (§8.4.4), and, after adapting the formal parameter types of N to the the type parameters of M, the same formal parameter types.
>
> The signature of a method m1 is a subsignature of the signature of a method m2 if either:
>
> - m2 has the same signature as m1, or
> - the signature of m1 is the same as the erasure (§4.6) of the signature of m2.
>
> Two method signatures m1 and m2 are override-equivalent iff either m1 is a subsignature of m2 or m2 is a subsignature of m1.

Because type parameters are part of the method signature, you can't add or remove type parameters in overriding methods.

> My ugly hack of a workaround...

Yes, it's ugly, but this is the right way to do it.

Comment: I see.  I suppose I had figured that, since T didn't affect the return type or parameters, then it didn't really "count" - but it does.  Thank you!

Comment: "*Yes, it's ugly, but this is the right way to do it.*" Nah, T is useless in the context of `realFoo`. It's completely unbounded and the compiler has no information to narrow it down (i.e. a return type or parameter). So it's just a confusing way of writing Object

Comment: Yup. As Michael said, @Dragon, this is horrible generics abuse. You get no type safety here at all. There is probably a link between 'this is not how you are supposed to use generics' and 'the java language spec gets in your way when you do'. (Usually, when you do 'weird' stuff, you run into problems such as the JLS blocking you, sooner rather than later). Maybe take a step back and try to state what you (think) the generics is trying to accomplish here. There is probably a better way than this mess.

Comment: @Michael it's not completely useless. If `getStuff` returns a `Map<T, List<T>>` then you can't treat it as a `Map<Object, List<Object>>`: without a type variable, you have to treat it as `Map<?, ? extends List<?>>`, which is gross, and you can't do things like (e.g.) add a key to a value list. The bound you get from the type variable gives you type information about the things in the map _with respect to each other_.

Comment: I spent some time looking at the example and concluded that the whole thing is a bit of a mindbender because there is no way for `getStuff` to provably return anything useful. That is the crux of what's confusing. There are 3 things it can provably return: null, an empty map, or a map containing null->null. Everything else requires an unsafe cast. When you have a method that can't possibly return anything useful, it seems unsurprising that it has knock-on effects to its callers. https://ideone.com/l6TaxI

Comment: "when you have a method that can't possibly return anything useful" what about if it returned `new HashMap<>()`?

Comment: @AndyTurner "*null, **an empty map**, or a map containing null->null*" I said that one and used it in my runnable example. I suppose, yes, an empty map isn't useless, but given that we have `Collections.emptyMap()`, it seems unlikely you'd need to declare it again. OP's also relying on the entry set, so is expecting it to be non-null and at least plausibly non-empty.